# In nixos, how to get vim syntax highlighting for the nix language?

Tags: vim, nix, nixos

I'm trying to add vim syntax highlighting for the nix language, and have been trying to use [this](https://github.com/LnL7/vim-nix) github repo to do that.

Within that repo I've located the [`nix.vim` file](https://github.com/LnL7/vim-nix/tree/master/plugin). I've tried placing that in `~/.vim` per the repository's 'manual installation' instructions, but this did not work to make the colors appear.

Since that attempt, I've been trying to get the syntax coloring by altering my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file, and in that vein have been trying to make sense out of [this documentation](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Vim). Thus I've added to my configuration file this `programs.vim` code block,

```
programs.vim = {
  enable = true;
  extraConfig = ''
  '';
};
```

and pasted the contents of the entire `nix.vim` file into the string of that `programs.vim.extraConfig` section. Thus block added to my `configuration.nix` is:

```
programs.vim = {
  enable = true;
  extraConfig = ''
" Vim syntax file
" Language:    Nix
" Maintainer:  Daiderd Jordan <daiderd@gmail.com>
" URL:         https://github.com/LnL7/vim-nix

if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

syn keyword nixBoolean     true false
syn keyword nixNull        null
syn keyword nixRecKeyword  rec

syn keyword nixOperator or
syn match   nixOperator '!=\|!'
syn match   nixOperator '<=\?'
syn match   nixOperator '>=\?'
syn match   nixOperator '&&'
syn match   nixOperator '//\='
syn match   nixOperator '=='
syn match   nixOperator '?'
syn match   nixOperator '||'
syn match   nixOperator '++\='
syn match   nixOperator '-'
syn match   nixOperator '\*'
syn match   nixOperator '->'

syn match nixParen '[()]'
syn match nixInteger '\d\+'

syn keyword nixTodo FIXME NOTE TODO OPTIMIZE XXX HACK contained
syn match   nixComment '#.*' contains=nixTodo,@Spell
syn region  nixComment start=+/\*+ end=+\*/+ contains=nixTodo,@Spell

syn region nixInterpolation matchgroup=nixInterpolationDelimiter start="\${" end="}" contained contains=@nixExpr,nixInterpolationParam

syn match nixSimpleStringSpecial /\\\%([nrt"\\$]\|$\)/ contained
syn match nixStringSpecial /''['$]/ contained
syn match nixStringSpecial /\$\$/ contained
syn match nixStringSpecial /''\\[nrt]/ contained

syn match nixInvalidSimpleStringEscape /\\[^nrt"\\$]/ contained
syn match nixInvalidStringEscape /''\\[^nrt]/ contained

syn region nixSimpleString matchgroup=nixStringDelimiter start=+"+ skip=+\\"+ end=+"+ contains=nixInterpolation,nixSimpleStringSpecial,nixInvalidSimpleStringEscape
syn region nixString matchgroup=nixStringDelimiter start=+''+ skip=+''['$\\]+ end=+''+ contains=nixInterpolation,nixStringSpecial,nixInvalidStringEscape

syn match nixFunctionCall "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*"

syn match nixPath "[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]*\%(/[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]\+\)\+"
syn match nixHomePath "\~\%(/[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]\+\)\+"
syn match nixSearchPath "[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]\+\%(\/[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]\+\)*" contained
syn match nixPathDelimiter "[<>]" contained
syn match nixSearchPathRef "<[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]\+\%(\/[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]\+\)*>" contains=nixSearchPath,nixPathDelimiter
syn match nixURI "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*:[a-zA-Z0-9%/?:@&=$,_.!~*'+-]\+"

syn match nixAttributeDot "\." contained
syn match nixAttribute "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\ze\%([^a-zA-Z0-9_'.-]\|$\)" contained
syn region nixAttributeAssignment start="=" end="\ze;" contained contains=@nixExpr
syn region nixAttributeDefinition start=/\ze[a-zA-Z_"$]/ end=";" contained contains=nixComment,nixAttribute,nixInterpolation,nixSimpleString,nixAttributeDot,nixAttributeAssignment

syn region nixInheritAttributeScope start="(" end=")" contained contains=nixComment,nixAttributeDot
syn region nixAttributeDefinition matchgroup=nixInherit start="\<inherit\>" end=";" contained contains=nixComment,nixInheritAttributeScope,nixAttribute

syn region nixAttributeSet start="{" end="}" contains=nixComment,nixAttributeDefinition

"                                                                                                              vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
syn region nixArgumentDefinitionWithDefault matchgroup=nixArgumentDefinition start="[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\ze\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*?\@=" matchgroup=NONE end="[,}]\@=" transparent contained contains=@nixExpr
"                                                           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
syn match nixArgumentDefinition "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\ze\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*[,}]\@=" contained
syn match nixArgumentEllipsis "\.\.\." contained
syn match nixArgumentSeparator "," contained

"                          vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                        vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
syn match nixArgOperator '@\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*:'he=s+1 contained contains=nixAttribute

"                                                 vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
syn match nixArgOperator '[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*@'hs=e-1 contains=nixAttribute nextgroup=nixFunctionArgument

" This is a bit more complicated, because function arguments can be passed in a
" very similar form on how attribute sets are defined and two regions with the
" same start patterns will shadow each other. Instead of a region we could use a
" match on {\_.\{-\}}, which unfortunately doesn't take nesting into account.
"
" So what we do instead is that we look forward until we are sure that it's a
" function argument. Unfortunately, we need to catch comments and both vertical
" and horizontal white space, which the following regex should hopefully do:
"
" "\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*"
"
" It is also used throught the whole file and is marked with 'v's as well.
"
" Fortunately the matching rules for function arguments are much simpler than
" for real attribute sets, because we can stop when we hit the first ellipsis or
" default value operator, but we also need to paste the "whitespace & comments
" eating" regex all over the place (marked with 'v's):
"
" Region match 1: { foo ? ... } or { foo, ... } or { ... } (ellipsis)
"                                         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv   {----- identifier -----}vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
syn region nixFunctionArgument start="{\ze\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*\%([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*[,?}]\|\.\.\.\)" end="}" contains=nixComment,nixArgumentDefinitionWithDefault,nixArgumentDefinition,nixArgumentEllipsis,nixArgumentSeparator nextgroup=nixArgOperator

" Now it gets more tricky, because we need to look forward for the colon, but
" there could be something like "{}@foo:", even though it's highly unlikely.
"
" Region match 2: {}
"                                         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv@vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv{----- identifier -----}  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
syn region nixFunctionArgument start="{\ze\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*}\%(\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*@\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\)\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*:" end="}" contains=nixComment nextgroup=nixArgOperator

"                                                               vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
syn match nixSimpleFunctionArgument "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\ze\%(\s\|#.\{-\}\n\|\n\|/\*\_.\{-\}\*/\)*:/\@!"

syn region nixList matchgroup=nixListBracket start="\[" end="\]" contains=@nixExpr

syn region nixLetExpr matchgroup=nixLetExprKeyword start="\<let\>" end="\<in\>" contains=nixComment,nixAttributeDefinition

syn keyword nixIfExprKeyword then contained
syn region nixIfExpr matchgroup=nixIfExprKeyword start="\<if\>" end="\<else\>" contains=@nixExpr,nixIfExprKeyword

syn region nixWithExpr matchgroup=nixWithExprKeyword start="\<with\>" matchgroup=NONE end=";" contains=@nixExpr

syn region nixAssertExpr matchgroup=nixAssertKeyword start="\<assert\>" matchgroup=NONE end=";" contains=@nixExpr

syn cluster nixExpr contains=nixBoolean,nixNull,nixOperator,nixParen,nixInteger,nixRecKeyword,nixConditional,nixBuiltin,nixSimpleBuiltin,nixComment,nixFunctionCall,nixFunctionArgument,nixSimpleFunctionArgument,nixPath,nixHomePath,nixSearchPathRef,nixURI,nixAttributeSet,nixList,nixSimpleString,nixString,nixLetExpr,nixIfExpr,nixWithExpr,nixAssertExpr,nixInterpolation

" These definitions override @nixExpr and have to come afterwards:

syn match nixInterpolationParam "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\%(\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_'-]*\)*" contained

" Non-namespaced Nix builtins as of version 2.0:
syn keyword nixSimpleBuiltin
      \ abort baseNameOf derivation derivationStrict dirOf fetchGit
      \ fetchMercurial fetchTarball import isNull map placeholder removeAttrs
      \ scopedImport throw toString


" Namespaced and non-namespaced Nix builtins as of version 2.0:
syn keyword nixNamespacedBuiltin contained
      \ abort add addErrorContext all any attrNames attrValues baseNameOf
      \ catAttrs compareVersions concatLists concatStringsSep currentSystem
      \ currentTime deepSeq derivation derivationStrict dirOf div elem elemAt
      \ fetchGit fetchMercurial fetchTarball fetchurl filter \ filterSource
      \ findFile foldl' fromJSON functionArgs genList \ genericClosure getAttr
      \ getEnv hasAttr hasContext hashString head import intersectAttrs isAttrs
      \ isBool isFloat isFunction isInt isList isNull isString langVersion
      \ length lessThan listToAttrs map match mul nixPath nixVersion
      \ parseDrvName partition path pathExists placeholder readDir readFile
      \ removeAttrs replaceStrings scopedImport seq sort split splitVersion
      \ storeDir storePath stringLength sub substring tail throw toFile toJSON
      \ toPath toString toXML trace tryEval typeOf unsafeDiscardOutputDependency
      \ unsafeDiscardStringContext unsafeGetAttrPos valueSize

syn match nixBuiltin "builtins\.[a-zA-Z']\+"he=s+9 contains=nixComment,nixNamespacedBuiltin

hi def link nixArgOperator               Operator
hi def link nixArgumentDefinition        Identifier
hi def link nixArgumentEllipsis          Operator
hi def link nixAssertKeyword             Keyword
hi def link nixAttribute                 Identifier
hi def link nixAttributeDot              Operator
hi def link nixBoolean                   Boolean
hi def link nixBuiltin                   Special
hi def link nixComment                   Comment
hi def link nixConditional               Conditional
hi def link nixHomePath                  Include
hi def link nixIfExprKeyword             Keyword
hi def link nixInherit                   Keyword
hi def link nixInteger                   Integer
hi def link nixInterpolation             Macro
hi def link nixInterpolationDelimiter    Delimiter
hi def link nixInterpolationParam        Macro
hi def link nixInvalidSimpleStringEscape Error
hi def link nixInvalidStringEscape       Error
hi def link nixLetExprKeyword            Keyword
hi def link nixNamespacedBuiltin         Special
hi def link nixNull                      Constant
hi def link nixOperator                  Operator
hi def link nixPath                      Include
hi def link nixPathDelimiter             Delimiter
hi def link nixRecKeyword                Keyword
hi def link nixSearchPath                Include
hi def link nixSimpleBuiltin             Keyword
hi def link nixSimpleFunctionArgument    Identifier
hi def link nixSimpleString              String
hi def link nixSimpleStringSpecial       SpecialChar
hi def link nixString                    String
hi def link nixStringDelimiter           Delimiter
hi def link nixStringSpecial             Special
hi def link nixTodo                      Todo
hi def link nixURI                       Include
hi def link nixWithExprKeyword           Keyword

" This could lead up to slow syntax highlighting for large files, but usually
" large files such as all-packages.nix are one large attribute set, so if we'd
" use sync patterns we'd have to go back to the start of the file anyway
syn sync fromstart

let b:current_syntax = "nix"
  '';
};
```

This gives me problems on the line `syn match nixStringSpecial /''['$]/ contained` because of the double-quotes `''` prematurely ending the nix string.

At this point I'm not sure whether I should try to sort out the string delimiting issues here, or try something else. Is this on the right track towards getting vim highlighting for the nix language working on my nixos machine?

Comment: Where exactly did you copy the `nix.vim` file? It needs to be inside `~/.vim/syntax` and you need to add the following line to your `.vimrc`: `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.nix set filetype=nix`

Comment: @GiftZwergrapper I had placed `nix.vim` properly at `~/.vim/syntax`, and it was simply your suggestion to add the `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.nix set filetype=nix` to `.vimrc` that got it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment above the solution to get it working is the following:

The `nix.vim` syntax file needs to be placed inside the `~/.vim/syntax` directory and the following line needs to be added to your `.vimrc`:

`au BufRead,BufNewFile *.nix set filetype=nix`

This line ensures that vim recognizes the filetype of `.nix` files and activates the correct syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

Put the plugin files in the proper runtimepath directories.

One solution with packages is

```
# git clone https://github.com/LnL7/vim-nix ~/.vim/pack/nix-stuff/start/vim-nix
```

Adjust accordingly if you version `.vim` with git and want to use submodules.

---

Summarising [Plugin layout in the dark ages](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html) and `:h runtimepath`, vim looks for plugin scripts in the following places on the runtimepath:

```
      filetype.vim  filetypes by file name |new-filetype|
      scripts.vim   filetypes by file contents |new-filetype-scripts|
      autoload/ automatically loaded scripts |autoload-functions|
      colors/   color scheme files |:colorscheme|
      compiler/ compiler files |:compiler|
      doc/      documentation |write-local-help|
      ftplugin/ filetype plugins |write-filetype-plugin|
      indent/   indent scripts |indent-expression|
      keymap/   key mapping files |mbyte-keymap|
      lang/     menu translations |:menutrans|
      menu.vim  GUI menus |menu.vim|
      pack/     packages |:packadd|
      plugin/   plugin scripts |write-plugin|
      print/    files for printing |postscript-print-encoding|
      spell/    spell checking files |spell|
      syntax/   syntax files |mysyntaxfile|
      tutor/    files for vimtutor |tutor|
```

Notice how certain locations have semantic meaning: syntax versus filetype versus generic "load all the time" plugins.

Now, getting all the plugin files to the right spots is tricky:

> In the past, when you wanted to use a plugin someone else wrote you would download the files and place them, one-by-one, into the appropriate directories. You could also use `zip` or `tar` to do the placing for you.
>
> There are a few significant problems with this approach:
>
> What happens when you want to update a plugin? You can overwrite the old files, but how do you know if the author deleted a file that you now need to delete by hand?
>
> What if two plugins happen to have a file with the same name (like utils.vim or something generic like that)? Sometimes you can simply rename it, but if it's in autoload/ or another directory where the names matter you've got to edit the plugin yourself. Not fun.
>
> People came up with several hacks to try to make things easier, like Vimballs. Luckily we don't need to suffer through these ugly hacks any more. ([A New Hope, Steve Losh](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/43.html))

The result is that most vim plugins on github are structured after `'runtimepath'` entries. They have syntax, ftplugin, or compiler directories as needed.

Pre vim-8, the standard solution was one of the many plugin managers (give it a Google; there are a lot). My favorite was pathogen from Tim Pope, because it worked so elegantly with submodules.

Since vim-8, I've moved to using packages, which you can read about at `:h packages`.